# ¿Obtener y eliminar un valor aleatorio de un array regenerando índices?

Tags: php

Tengo un array, por ejemplo:

```
Array
(
    [0] => tomato
    [1] => apple
    [2] => melon
    [3] => cherry
    [4] => banana
)
```

Obtengó uno de sus elementos de forma aleatorio y lo eliminó del propio array, regenerando al tiempo sus indices, de forma que tras la extracción quedaría, por ejemplo:

```
Array
(
    [0] => tomato
    [1] => apple
    [2] => melon
    [3] => banana
)
//Extraído el elemento anteriormente en la posición 3
```

¿hay alguna forma mejor de regenerar los índices que la siguiente?:

```
$arr = [
    'tomato',
    'apple',
    'melon',
    'cherry',
    'banana',
];

//Obtiene la posición del elemento a extraer:
$pos   = mt_rand(0, (count($arr) - 1));

//Extraer elemento regenerando índices:
$value = array_values(array_splice($arr, $pos, 1))[0];

//Ver elemento extraído:
echo $value;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma de hacerlo sería la siguiente:

- Con `unset` remueves el elemento ubicado en la posición aleatoria.
- Con `array_values` reorganizas el array.

  ```
  unset($arr[$pos]);
  $arrNuevo = array_values($arr);
  ```
- Si te interesa obtener el elemento que ha sido removido, lo puedes hacer así, antes de aplicar el `unset`:

  ```
  $valor=$arr[$pos];
  ```

---

Veamos un ejemplo completo, usando una función

<kbd>**[PROBAR CÓDIGO EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/FRGI55358)**</kbd>

### Código:

```
<?php
/*PHP: Eliminar elemento aleatorio de array y reordenar - https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/132683/29967*/
$arr = [
    'tomato',
    'apple',
    'melon',
    'cherry',
    'banana',
];

echo 'Array antes del cambio: '.PHP_EOL;
print_r($arr);

removerAleatorio($arr);
removerAleatorio($arr);
removerAleatorio($arr);

function removerAleatorio($arr){
    $pos = mt_rand(0, (count($arr) - 1));

    /*Obtener valor a remover*/
    $valor=$arr[$pos];

    /*Sacar valor del array*/
    echo 'Vamos a remover el índice '.$pos.' cuyo valor es '.$valor.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
    unset($arr[$pos]);

    /*Crear nuevo array re-ordenado*/
    echo 'Nuevo array: '.PHP_EOL;
    $arrNuevo = array_values($arr); 
    print_r($arrNuevo);
}

?>
```

### Resultado:

```
Array antes del cambio: 
Array
(
    [0] => tomato
    [1] => apple
    [2] => melon
    [3] => cherry
    [4] => banana
)
Vamos a remover el índice 4 cuyo valor es banana

Nuevo array: 
Array
(
    [0] => tomato
    [1] => apple
    [2] => melon
    [3] => cherry
)
Vamos a remover el índice 0 cuyo valor es tomato

Nuevo array: 
Array
(
    [0] => apple
    [1] => melon
    [2] => cherry
    [3] => banana
)
Vamos a remover el índice 3 cuyo valor es cherry

Nuevo array: 
Array
(
    [0] => tomato
    [1] => apple
    [2] => melon
    [3] => banana
)
```